# Can you start a sentence with "Hopefully,..."?

Tags: grammaticality, adverbs, sentence-starts

I am studying for the SAT, and I learned just now that the following sentence is grammatically incorrect:

> Hopefully, we will be able to complete the building before the rainy season sets in.

The reason why it's incorrect is given in my study book: *hopefully* is an adverb, and yet it is not modifying a verb in this sentence.

I don't see how this is the case, because *hopefully* is modifying the verb *complete*. And why is that according to Google Dictionary, the following sentence is correct:

> Hopefully, it should be finished by next year.

Comment: It's modifying the whole clause, not just the 'verb complete'. And you better find a new study book, because the author of this one clearly did not understand either English or grammar.

Comment: Sentence adverbs are perfectly legal "Lately, I've come to appreciate the follies of youth". But 'hopefully' is problematic. Some people say that it should only be used to modify a verb directly or that you should just say 'I hope...' instead. Others say it is OK. [Grammar Girl has the best advice to help you on SATs](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/starting-a-sentence-with-hopefully) but not necessarily real life. I guess the editor at the New Yorker might have a tiz fit if you used it as a sentence adverb; they also avoid splitting very splittable infinitives.

Comment: Related, possible duplicates: *[What's the correct usage of “hopefully”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1521)*, *[Why is “hopefully” treated so mercilessly?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24031)*, and *[Can one use “hopefully” in an absolute sense?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/109870)*

Comment: Which is a long way to say, on SATs you probably don't want to use 'hopefully' as a sentence adverb, but most everywhere else is OK with that. Hopefully.

Comment: Guideline: if it's widely used and well-understood by English speakers, it's correct. The reactionary grammarians will catch up with reality eventually.

Answer (score 2):

The case of [hopefully](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopefully) is a bit different here.

It is a sentence adverb, a [disjunct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunct_%28linguistics%29#Hopefully). It is modifying the whole sentence. Rather than `in a hopeful manner`, it means `it is hoped` in this case.

<sub>Wikipedia</sub>

---

[Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/hopefully)'s dictionary entry states this meaning and usage as valid, though it warns that some people think it is incorrect:

> Although this is the most common use of hopefully, it is a fairly new use and some people think it is not correct.

It is worth noting that this usage has been accepted by oxford. [See this article.](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2012/05/is-it-ok-to-use-hopefully-as-a-sentence-adverb/)

> ...the acceptance of hopefully when used as a sentence adverb. That is to say, **the AP Stylebook no longer considers the use of hopefully to mean ‘it is hoped’** (as opposed to the less common meaning of ‘in a hopeful manner’) **to be a sin worthy of stoning.**

I think all but the most pedantic of speakers would accept this usage as correct.

Comment: Amen. I remember this usage being excoriated in my youth, but I thought that the opponents had all died off. I don't like it myself, but we lost the Hundred Years' War as well and learned to live with it.

Comment: @DavidPugh; Good to hear. I've always wondered: why `hopefully`? Out of all the sentence adverbs, why single this one out for persecution? Anyway, nobody in the Indian subcontinent raises an eyebrow, so...

Comment: @DavidPugh: Speaking of continents, which one are you on these days?

Comment: Europe. Still enjoying the amenities....

Comment: @DavidPugh: Cool. Nobody should have to spend a single day without wifi.